# Is there any memory leak in this code?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int * k;
    char m;
    do{
        cin >> j;
        k = new int[j];
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++){
            k[i] = i;
            cout << k[i] << ", ";
        }

        delete[] k;

        cout << "\nContinue?\n";
        cin >> m;
    }while (m != 'n');
}
```

This is a program I made to describe my problem in understanding `new` and `delete`. Will 'k' produce memory leak?

Comment: Why do you believe that there might be a leak?

Comment: Don't use `new` and `delete` directly, no memory leaks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code is not exception safe - if an exception is thrown between `new[]` and `delete[]` the block pointed to is leaked. Use `std::vector` to resolve this problem.

Comment: @Sagi Nothing is stopping `cout` or one of the insertion operators from throwing.  I don't think that the operations on an `int[]` can throw, but `iostream`s definitely can.

Comment: First, I'd like to agree that sharptooth's point is something one really should *habitually* guard against. For this *specific* program, exactly as is, I think the only way an exception can be raised between `new` and `delete` is by an error in the C++ library.

Comment: @Hurkyl: it can throw std::bad_alloc and std::bad_exception

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by sharptooth, you should use a try-catch block to make sure any exception is caught and `k` is released.
In a general case, you can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html) to check if your program is freeing all blocks that were allocated during execution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not in this instance as you free the memory within the loop. However, you'd be much better of using a [scoped_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) in this instance.